# Toggle Angular animation

Tags: angular, animation

I have animation in angular which name is `slideInOut` and looks like this:

```
slideInOut = trigger('slideInOut', [
 transition('void => true', [animate('250ms')])
 transition('true=> void', [animate('250ms')])
]);
```

Now in template it is used like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let animatedElement of animatedElements'>
 <div [@slideInOut]='isAnimated' class='animated-element'>
  {{animatedElement}}
 </div>
</ng-container>
<button (click)="toggleAnimations()"></button>
```

In component I can add new elements.
It doen't work as expected. The animation is turned off after element was added.

```
i click button to turn off animation --> i add element --> it is still aniamted --> i add another element --> animation is turned off
```

Comment: I'd recommend creating a stackblitz so we can see more of what is going on.